# Make loop for ajax call in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to send email to > 2000 recipients. I make a ajax call that sends 50 email and i want to repeat it until all emails will send. PHP function returns an array with 3 index, Success (count success mail), failed (count failed mail) and Finish (determine no more email exists). So, I get email count to counts and I use a counter (i) to determine how many email is sent. I want to break loop when i >= counts. Here is my code:

```
function sendEmailStepByStep(imageAddress, counts) {
    $(".feature div").append("<br />Please wait...<div class='feature_process'>&nbsp;</div>" + "<div class='feature_message'>Success: <span id='success_email'>0</span>, Failed:    <span id='failed_email'>0</span></div>");

    var i = 0;
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                group: 'packages',
                do :'emailPackageUsingAjax',
                image: imageAddress,
                num: i
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(response);
            $("#success_email").html(response.Success);
            $("#failed_email").html(response.Failed);
            i = i + response.Success + response.Failed;
            if (i > counts || response.Finish == 'true') {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
        }).fail(function (response) {
            $(".feature_message").append(response.responseText);
            console.log("error");
            console.log(response);
            clearTimeout(timer);
        })
    }, 1000);
}
```

Why this is called just once?

Comment: I don't get a setInterval, I see a setTimeout...Why would it run more than once

Comment: Where i must add interval?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp in opposition to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp Timeout calls code after some time, interval calls it repeatedly

Comment: setTimeout = Runs after interval time specified, setInterval = runs every interval time specified.

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you. What about break condition? Is it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using setTimeout or setInterval I would recommend something like this:

```
function sendEmailStepByStep(imageAddress, counts) {
$(".feature div").append("<br />Please wait...<div class='feature_process'>&nbsp;</div>" + "<div class='feature_message'>Success: <span id='success_email'>0</span>, Failed:    <span id='failed_email'>0</span></div>");

var i = 0;
var mailer = function () {      // Create internal function instead of timer
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            group: 'packages',
            do :'emailPackageUsingAjax',
            image: imageAddress,
            num: i
        }
    }).done(function (response) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(response);
        $("#success_email").html(response.Success);
        $("#failed_email").html(response.Failed);
        i = i + response.Success + response.Failed;
        if (i < counts && response.Finish != 'true') {
            mailer();     // if count is less and not finished, invoke function again
        }
    }).fail(function (response) {
        $(".feature_message").append(response.responseText);
        console.log("error");
        console.log(response);
    })
};

mailer();     // First invocation of function
}
```

Using above technique will ensure that next batch is sent only when the previous one is completed, even when it takes more than 1 sec, as you set in timeout.